# How can I boost performance when passing large python lists into SQLite SELECT statements?

Tags: python-3.x, list, performance, sqlite

I've been running into huge performance slowdowns when looping over  strings in a large python list and passing them into SQLite SELECT statements to return values, it takes 0.5s to 0.7s per loop. (~2hrs for 10K strings)

After pervasive searching, I'm unsure of how to implement a method to maybe "batch" export the list into fewer consolidated queries in hopes of gaining speed.

I have this generated list of file names from a function:

`documents = ['value1.xlsx', 'value2.docx', 'value3.txt', 'value4.csv', ...]`

I also have a large 1GB database full of unique File Names and File Hashes.

```
def iterate_documents(cur, documents):
    i = 0
    output = [] # Declare Empty List
    while i < len(documents):
        # Returning the MD5 Hash of a Passed File Name
        match = cur.execute('SELECT md5hash FROM hash_table WHERE name=?', (documents[i],)).fetchone()

        # If a File Name hasn't been seen by the DB, say the hash is "Unknown"
        if match is None or len(match) == 0:
            match = "Unknown"
        else:
            match = match[0]

        output.append(match) # Append the match or 'Unknown' to the Output List
        i += 1
    return output
```

Sample Output: `hashes = [hash-1, hash-2, Unknown, value-4, ...]`

What I do next is use the ordered output to match documents and hashes in tuples `(documents[i], hashes[i])`. Example: `('value1.xlsx', 'hash-1')`

So I need the `iterate_documents()` values to stay in order they were passed. Thus far, brute-force looping is the best I got!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options for python performance without doing much code modification.

1.) You can use PyPy

This one will be the easiest way

PyPy is a runtime interpreter that is faster than a fully interpreted language, but it's slower than a fully compiled language such as C.

[PyPY Link](https://www.pypy.org/)

2.) You can try multi threading or parallel processing

This will be more difficult

[Threading Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

With code modifications you have a couple of options as well.

1.) Use a for loop instead of a while loop

For loops are faster in python but not in C

[Comparing for loops to while loops](https://www.pythonpool.com/for-vs-while-loop-python/#:%7E:text=While%20loop%20cannot%20be%20iterated%20on%20Generators%20directly.&text=For%20loop%20with%20range(),C%2C%20so%2C%20its%20faster.&text=On%20basis%20of%20disassembly%2C%20for%20loop%20is%20faster%20than%20while%20loop.)

2.) Don't pass the variable `documents` to the function
The variable `documents` is an mutable value and changes as well as gets larger.
This creates problems with functions because you are recreating the var every time

Answer (score 0):

since it is only 10k items, I might just fetch the ones you need from the database once then do the match more locally:

```
import sqlite3

def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

conn.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hash_table(
        name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        md5hash TEXT
    );
''')
conn.execute("INSERT INTO hash_table(name,md5hash) VALUES ('value1.xlsx', 'some hash of value1.xlsx');")
conn.execute("INSERT INTO hash_table(name,md5hash) VALUES ('value2.docx', 'some hash of value2.docx');")

documents = ['value1.xlsx', 'value2.docx', 'value3.txt', 'value4.csv']
lookup = {}

## -----------------------
## load the lookup in chunks due to limits of SQLLite
# ## -----------------------
chunck_size = 100
for chunc in chunks(documents, chunck_size):
    sql = f"SELECT name, md5hash FROM hash_table WHERE name in ({','.join(['?']*len(chunc))})"
    lookup = {**lookup, **dict(conn.execute(sql, chunc).fetchall())}
## -----------------------

doc_with_hash = {doc: lookup.get(doc, "Unknown") for doc in documents}
print(doc_with_hash)
```

That should give you:

```
{
    'value1.xlsx': 'some hash of value1.xlsx',
    'value2.docx': 'some hash of value2.docx',
    'value3.txt': 'Unknown',
    'value4.csv': 'Unknown'
}
```